# Loading objects with new restkit

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit

I'm new to the new RestKit 0.20, so I'm a bit unsure of the best practices when updating from 0.10.
I used to use an RKRequest object and an RKResponse object to manage loading simple one-time use JSON objects from an HTTP response. With the new RKObjectRequestOperation, I need to supply an object mapping to accomplish everything, but I'd rather not have to create an object and an object mapping for each request which has its own type of JSON object (3 in total, each with a single field). Is there any other way to use RKObjectRequestOperation without having to define new objects to load into? Do I have to use RKObjectRequestOperation if I want to use RestKit to accomplish this?